# iOS 3.x support in 2012?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-3.x

I'm developing an app that works on iOS 5 and it appears that Xcode automatically says "iOS 4.3 or newer". Can I still (in 2012!) create apps that work on **iOS 3.x?**

Many people have iPhone 3G or even the original iPhone, and these are so old that it's not wise to run newer iOS versions than 3.x on them. These people would be excluded from getting the app, which is a pity.

If my app doesn't use any features that an iPhone 3G with iOS 3.1.3 wouldn't have, can I publish the app to require "iOS 3.1 or newer"?

Comment: **Update:** I found these fairly recent statistics that shows the futility of worrying over old versions and devices: [be-rad.com](http://www.be-rad.com/2012/03/15/ios-device-usage-statistics/), [marco.org](http://www.marco.org/2011/08/13/instapaper-ios-device-and-version-stats-update)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. But you certainly don't have to. The people who are not on at least iOS 4.0 are under 3% based on the usage statistics I'm seen. I wouldn't worry about it too much.

"can I publish the app to require "iOS 3.1 or newer"?"  Yes.

Comment: 3%? Wow, that's too few to worry about. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

In Xcode, you can set the minimum iOS version as far back as 3.x. Just to be sure, weak link any libraries that didn't exist back then, and check for method support where appropriate. (Use `respondsToSelector()` etc.)

Two things to note:

1. iOS 5 adoption is really widespread.
2. Note that Xcode only compiles for armv7 by default, so you'll have to do extra legwork to support older hardware, regardless of the iOS version that they're running. This is as simple as changing a setting in your project settings, but it shows what Apple thinks about supporting such old devices. You technically can. But don't.

Answer (score 2):

If I was you I would not waste time coding for old version or platform. As you know and we all know each line of code is precious. However the market has captured by iOS4.3+ at the moment.

And if you really think you should support all phone then, and if it is not late! Create web based application which has advantages such as platform independency. try,

1. [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/)
2. [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)